# Imagick unable to show conversion result

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

I am running the code bellow. I am using Windows 10. I saved the code bellow in my C:/xampp/htdocs/files/

```
$imagick = new Imagick(); 
$imagick->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/file1.pdf");
$imagick->writeImages($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/file1.jpg", false);
```

But the problem is my browser can't load the page.

[Click here to view the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTKtN.png)

Comment: Perhaps your path is not correct. Print out the path to the image when running your script and check that the image is where the path claims to be looking.

Comment: You should include the text of the error message here instead of linking to a screen shot of it. That said, the error you get doesn't sound so much like a code error, and more like a server configuration error. If you put no code at all in your file, just a "hello" message, does that work? If not, please include more information about your server configuration, the name of the file you're trying to access, what URL you're trying to access it through, etc. in order to help us help you track down the source.

Answer (score 0):

please check the folder permission on "files" first.